# Convert char* into char [ ]

Tags: c++, arrays, char, type-conversion

Hello dear Internet :D

So i coded a "Text to morse" translator which worked well. Now i want to do the same with an arduino. The morse code should be shown by a blinking led.
My problem ist that i have a `const char* morse[]={"....", ".-", ".-..", ".-..", "---"};` which i cant convert or reassign to a new variable `char str[]` to give the correct output with the led.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SHORT 2
#define LONG 3
#define PAUSE 800

char sentence[50]="Hello";
const char* morse[500];


const static char* letters[50]={"10","0111","0101","011","1","1101","001","1111","11","1000","010","1011","00","01","000","1001","0010","101","111","0","110","1110","100","0110","0100","0011"}; //A-Z

void setup(){
  pinMode(SHORT, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SHORT, LOW);
  pinMode(LONG, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LONG, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  all_Caps();
}

void loop(){
  all_Caps();
  int b=strlen(sentence);
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++)morse[i]=letters[sentence[i]-'A'];
  showtime();

  delay(PAUSE*10);
}


void all_Caps(){
  int b=strlen(sentence);
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++){
        sentence[i]= toupper(sentence[i]);
    }
}


void showtime(){
  
  char str[10];
  
  
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    str=morse[i]; 
  }
  for(int e=0;e<10;e++){
    if(str[e]==1){
      digitalWrite(SHORT, HIGH);
      delay(50);
      digitalWrite(SHORT, LOW);
      delay(PAUSE);
    }
    else if(str[e]==0){
      digitalWrite(LONG, HIGH);
      delay(300);
      digitalWrite(LONG, LOW);
      delay(PAUSE);
    }
  }     
}
```

edit:

So i changed `str=morse[i]` to `str[i]=morse[i]` like the comments said.
Now i got the warning message:

`sketch_aug05a.ino:48:19: warning: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: `str[i] = morse[i];` it is wrong for sure :)

Comment: the @mch comment is wrong.

Comment: Arduino uses C++ compiler and it compiles the C++ code. You use classes in this code. For example `Serial.begin(9600);` you invoke the the `begin` method from the `Serial` class instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant assign strings, and it is not needed here

```
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
        showtime(letters[toupper(sentence[i])-'A']);
    }
```

```
void showtime(const char *code)
{
    while(*code)
    {
        if(*code++ == '1')
        {
            digitalWrite(SHORT, HIGH);
            delay(50);
            digitalWrite(SHORT, LOW);
        }
        else
        {
            digitalWrite(LONG, HIGH);
            delay(300);
            digitalWrite(LONG, LOW);
        }
        delay(PAUSE);
    }
}
```

Allcaps function is not needed.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped